Sitecore powershell Import-CSV cmdlet issue
I am importing csv file but I am seeing below error
Import-CSV : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Krishan.Kanoria\Desktop\Book2.csv'.


I am using this command in my PSE -
$importList = Import-CSV "C:\Users\Krishan.Kanoria\Desktop\Book2.csv"

Note -
PSE Version - 5.1 and 6
Can someone faced the same issue? Thanks in advance
Regards,
Krishan Kanoria
Edit 1
When I run this command under C drive, I can only see a few files.
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -File
Image1
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Krishan.Kanoria\Desktop -File
Image2
Edit 2
Just to update all - I am running this PSE command in XM cloud instance
Solution - I have the solution for this now - When there is a need to import csv file (In an XM cloud instance), we can use this -
   $File = Receive-File $SitecoreTempFolder
   if($File -ne "cancel" -and $File.EndsWith(".csv"))
   {
       $CsvData = Import-Csv $File
   }
   Remove-Item $File

Here, Receive-File will give you an option to upload a file. and, Remove-Item will delete the file

There is no much we can do to help you here, the error message states that the file in C:\Users\Krishan.Kanoria\Desktop\Book2.csv doesn't exist.

You claim to be using the statement $importList = Import-CSV "C:\Users\Krishan.Kanoria\Desktop\Test.csv" - but the error clearly shows you targeted a file named Book2.csv instead of Test.csv, maybe that's your problem?

@SantiagoSquarzon obviously file is present there and I have also given full access to this file itself but seeing this error. I tried to place this file other places as well but same error.

@KrishanKanoria Does Book2.csv show up in the list if you do Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Krishan.Kanoria\Desktop -File?

@MathiasR.Jessen it put the wrong path, now I have edited this.

@MathiasR.Jessen I have updated my ticket above. I ran the command that you suggested.

I suggest you inspect the contents of the C:\Users folder to see if there really is a folder called Krishan.Kanoria. Also, did you try to use the -LiteralPath parameter instead of -Path (which is implied if you leave that out in the command) ? So Import-Csv -LiteralPath ... and Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath ...

@Theo I am having Krishan.Kanoria folder inside the Users folder.
When I am checking if there is any file inside C:\ drive, it shows me only 3 files. I am using this command -> Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath C:\ -File. Please refer Image1 screenshot in the ticket description.

The C:  drive usually does not have that many files outside folders. If you append the -Force switch you will also see hidden and/or system files which are not enumerated without that switch.

I have the solution for this - When there is a need to import csv file (In an XM cloud instance), we can use this  -
$File = Receive-File $SitecoreTempFolder
if($File -ne "cancel" -and $File.EndsWith(".csv"))
{
$CsvData = Import-Csv $File
}
Remove-Item $File
Here, Receive-File will give you an option to upload a file.
and, Remove-Item will delete the file.
